# person name transformations [with diminutives]

Tags: java, python, string

I'm looking for an api/dictionary or any resource that can help me return variants of names I give it. e.g. If i pass "william defoe", it should return "w.defoe", "bill.d", "william.d", etc.

I haven't found any adequate resource online. My implementation can be either in python or java.

Comment: This is a really simple transformation, you should just create your own.

Comment: it's actually not so simple. that's why i included "bill.d". a simple transformation can't do this. i'm looking either for a dictionary or some kind of machine learning model.

Comment: I edited your question title to stress the need for diminutives. +1

Comment: bill d is the only transformation you listed that might cause trouble. But even then you don't need anything as complex as a machine learning model. You can just have a list of names and common nicknames for them stored in a data structure. I searched `name and nickname data` and got a hit with a listing of names and common nicknames: http://deron.meranda.us/data/nicknames.txt

Comment: i guess i was looking for something more involved. i'll try this and see the performance.

Comment: @Adinoyi I don't know about you, but I always look for the simplest way to get things done :P More involved means more hassle to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Database (must be purchased) called [pdNickname](http://www.peacockdata2.com/products/pdnickname/). I found it via this question: [Database of common name aliases / nicknames of people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381522/database-of-common-name-aliases-nicknames-of-people)

Searched Google for "nickname database" and it's the second result.

In addition to all that, the transformations - as pointed out by Hunter - are simple. You can implement those transformations in 5 minutes or less. The one you pointed out ("William" -> "Bill") is still quite simple, although you'll need a list of names -> nicknames hence the link to the above Database.

From their sample text

```
NAME      VARIATION          GENDER
------------------------------------
ABIGAIL    ABBEY               1F
ABIGAIL    ABBIE               2F
ABIGAIL    ABBY                3F
ABIGAIL    GAIL                4F
ABIGAIL    ABAEGAYLE           5F
ABIGAIL    ABAGAEL             6F
```

May be a bit of an overkill, but not all "Williams" like to be called "Bill" :P

**EDIT**

There is also an alternative on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/nickname-and-diminutive-names-lookup/source/browse/trunk/names.csv) which is a CSV of names and common nicknames/diminuntives.

Comment: thanks for the links. i'm aggregate this with others and see how it does.

Answer (score 0):

I created this C# class for my own dimunitive purpose. Should be easy to convert to java.

```
public static class Diminutives
{
    public static List<string> GetNames(string givenName)
    {
        // Diminutives of given name, most common first.
        switch (givenName)
        {
            case "Abigail":
                return new List<string> { "Abby", "Nabby" };
            case "Abraham":
            case "Abram":
                return new List<string> { "Abe", "Aby" };
            case "Agnes":
                return new List<string> { "Aggie", "Aggy" };
            case "Albert":
                return new List<string> { "Bert", "Bertie" };
            case "Alexander":
                return new List<string> { "Alec", "Alex", "Lex", "Sandy" };
            case "Alfred":
                return new List<string> { "Alf", "Fred", "Freddy", "Alfie" };
            case "Alice":
            case "Alicia":
                return new List<string> { "Ally", "Allie", "Elsie" };
            case "Andrew":
                return new List<string> { "Andy" };
            case "Ann":
            case "Anna":
            case "Anne":
            case "Annette":
                return new List<string> { "Annie" };
            case "Anthony":
            case "Antony":
                return new List<string> { "Tony", "Tone" };
            case "Antoinette":
                return new List<string> { "Netty", "Net" };
            case "Arabella":
                return new List<string> { "Bella", "Bel", "Belle" };
            case "Archibald":
                return new List<string> { "Archie", "Archy", "Baldie" };
            case "Augustus":
                return new List<string> { "Gus", "Gussie", "Gustus" };
            case "Barbara":
                return new List<string> { "Bab", "Babs", "Babbie" };
            case "Bartholomew":
                return new List<string> { "Bart", "Bat" };
            case "Benedict":
                return new List<string> { "Bennet" };
            case "Benjamin":
                return new List<string> { "Ben", "Benny" };
            case "Bernard":
                return new List<string> { "Barney" };
            case "Bertha":
            case "Bertram":
                return new List<string> { "Bertie", "Berty", "Bert" };
            case "Burton":
                return new List<string> { "Burt" };
            case "Caroline":
                return new List<string> { "Carrie", "Caddie", "Carol" };
            case "Casimir":
                return new List<string> { "Cassie", "Cas" };
            case "Catherine":
            case "Catherina":
            case "Katharine":
            case "Katherine":
                return new List<string> { "Katie", "Casy", "Kate", "Kathleen", "Cathie", "Kathie", "Kit", "Kitty" };
            case "Cecilia":
            case "Cecily":
                return new List<string> { "Cissy", "Sis", "Cis", "Cissie" };
            case "Charles":
                return new List<string> { "Charlie", "Charley" };
            case "Christian":
                return new List<string> { "Chris", "Christie", "Christy" };
            case "Christina":
                return new List<string> { "Chris", "Chrissy", "Chrissie", "Tina" };
            case "Christopher":
                return new List<string> { "Chris" };
            case "Clara":
            case "Clarice":
            case "Clarissa":
                return new List<string> { "Clare", "Claire" };
            case "Constance":
                return new List<string> { "Connie", "Conny" };
            case "Daniel":
                return new List<string> { "Dan", "Danny", "Dannie" };
            case "David":
                return new List<string> { "Dave", "Davy", "Davie" };
            case "Diana":
                return new List<string> { "Di", "Die" };
            case "Dorothea":
            case "Dorothy":
                return new List<string> { "Dolly", "Dol", "Dora", "Dollie" };
            case "Edmund":
                return new List<string> { "Ed", "Ned", "Neddy" };
            case "Edward":
                return new List<string> { "Ed", "Eddie", "Eddy", "Ned", "Neddy", "Ted", "Teddy" };
            case "Edwin":
                return new List<string> { "Ed", "Eddie", "Eddy" };
            case "Eleanor":
            case "Elinor":
            case "Leonora":
                return new List<string> { "Ella", "Ellen", "Nell", "Nellie", "Nora", "Norah" };
            case "Elisabeth":
            case "Eliza":
            case "Elizabeth":
                return new List<string> { "Beth", "Betsy", "Bess", "Bessie", "Bessy", "Betty", "Elsie", "Lisa", "Liza" };
            case "Elsbeth":
            case "Elspeth":
                return new List<string> { "Elspie", "Elsie" };
            case "Emeline":
            case "Emmeline":
            case "Emily":
            case "Emma":
                return new List<string> { "Emmy", "Emmie", "Emm" };
            case "Esther":
            case "Hester":
            case "Hesther":
                return new List<string> { "Essie", "Essy" };
            case "Eugenia":
                return new List<string> { "Genie" };
            case "Euphemia":
                return new List<string> { "Effie", "Euphie", "Phemie", "Phamie", "Effy" };
            case "Evelina":
            case "Eveline":
            case "Evelyn":
                return new List<string> { "Eva", "Eve" };
            case "Ezekial":
                return new List<string> { "Zeke" };
            case "Florence":
                return new List<string> { "Flo", "Flossie" };
            case "Frances":
                return new List<string> { "Fanny", "Fannie" };
            case "Francis":
                return new List<string> { "Frank", "Francie", "Frankie", "Franky" };
            case "Frederic":
            case "Frederick":
            case "Frederica":
            case "Frederico":
                return new List<string> { "Fred", "Freddie", "Freddy" };
            case "Gabriel":
                return new List<string> { "Gabe", "Gaby", "Gabby" };
            case "George":
                return new List<string> { "Dod", "Doddy", "Geordie", "Georgie" };
            case "Georgina":
            case "Georgiana":
                return new List<string> { "Georgie", "Georgy" };
            case "Gertrude":
                return new List<string> { "Gertie", "Gerty", "Trudy", "Trudie" };
            case "Gilbert":
                return new List<string> { "Gil" };
            case "Helen":
            case "Helena":
                return new List<string> { "Nell", "Nellie", "Lena" };
            case "Henrietta":
                return new List<string> { "Etta", "Hetty", "Nettie", "Netty" };
            case "Harold":
            case "Henry":
                return new List<string> { "Harry", "Harrie", "Hal", "Hen", "Henny" };
            case "Hugh":
            case "Hugo":
                return new List<string> { "Hughie" };
            case "Humphrey":
            case "Humphry":
                return new List<string> { "Humph" };
            case "Isaac":
            case "Izaak":
                return new List<string> { "Ike", "Ik" };
            case "James":
            case "Jacob":
            case "Jacov":
                return new List<string> { "Jim", "Jimmy", "Jemmy", "Jimmie", "Jem" };
            case "Jacomina":
                return new List<string> { "Mien" };
            case "Jane":
                return new List<string> { "Janet", "Jean", "Jeanie", "Jeannie", "Jeany" };
            case "Janet":
            case "Jennifer":
                return new List<string> { "Jenny", "Jennie", "Jen" };
            case "Jessie":
                return new List<string> { "Jess" };
            case "John":
                return new List<string> { "Johnnie", "Johnny", "Jack", "Jock" };
            case "Joseph":
                return new List<string> { "Joe", "Joey" };
            case "Josephine":
                return new List<string> { "Jo", "Josy", "Josie", "Jozy", "Pheny" };
            case "Joshua":
                return new List<string> { "Josh" };
            case "Judith":
                return new List<string> { "Judy", "Judie" };
            case "Julian":
            case "Julius":
                return new List<string> { "Jule" };
            case "Kathleen":
                return new List<string> { "Kathy", "Katie", "Kath" };
            case "Kenneth":
                return new List<string> { "Ken" };
            case "Laurence":
            case "Lawrence":
            case "Lorenzo":
                return new List<string> { "Larry", "Larrie" };
            case "Leonard":
                return new List<string> { "Lenny", "Len", "Lennie" };
            case "Letitia":
            case "Lettice":
                return new List<string> { "Letty", "Lettie" };
            case "Lewis":
            case "Louis":
            case "Ludovic":
                return new List<string> { "Lou", "Lewie", "Lew", "Louie" };
            case "Louisa":
            case "Louise":
                return new List<string> { "Lou", "Louie" };
            case "Madeline":
                return new List<string> { "Maud", "Maudlin" };
            case "Magdalene":
                return new List<string> { "Lena", "Maud" };
            case "Margaret":
                return new List<string> { "Margie", "Margy", "Marjory", "Marjorie", "Madge", "Mag", "Maggie", "Meg", "Meggy", "Peg", "Peggy" };
            case "Marion":
                return new List<string> { "Mamie" };
            case "Martha":
                return new List<string> { "Mat", "Matty", "Pat", "Patty", "Patti" };
            case "Mary":
            case "Miriam":
                return new List<string> { "May", "Moll", "Molly", "Mollie" };
            case "Matilda":
            case "Mathilda":
                return new List<string> { "Mat", "Mattie", "Matty", "Maud", "Tilda", "Tillie" };
            case "Matthew":
            case "Matthias":
                return new List<string> { "Matt", "Mat" };
            case "Michael":
                return new List<string> { "Mike", "Micky", "Mickey" };
            case "Moses":
                return new List<string> { "Mose", "Mosey" };
            case "Nancy":
                return new List<string> { "Nan", "Nance", "Nina" };
            case "Nicholas":
            case "Nicolas":
                return new List<string> { "Nick", "Nic", "Nicky" };
            case "Oliver":
                return new List<string> { "Ollie", "Olly", "Nol", "Nolly" };
            case "Patrick":
                return new List<string> { "Pat", "Paddy" };
            case "Patricia":
                return new List<string> { "Pat", "Patty" };
            case "Peter":
                return new List<string> { "Pete" };
            case "Philip":
                return new List<string> { "Phil", "Pip" };
            case "Philippa":
                return new List<string> { "Pippa" };
            case "Prudence":
                return new List<string> { "Prue", "Prudy" };
            case "Raymond":
            case "Raymund":
                return new List<string> { "Ray" };
            case "Rebecca":
            case "Rebekah":
                return new List<string> { "Beck", "Bex", "Becky", "Beckie" };
            case "Reginald":
            case "Reynold":
                return new List<string> { "Reg", "Reggie", "Reggy" };
            case "Richard":
                return new List<string> { "Dick", "Dickie", "Dicky", "Rick", "Ricky", "Rickie" };
            case "Robert":
            case "Rupert":
                return new List<string> { "Bob", "Bobby", "Bobbie", "Rob", "Robby", "Robbie", "Robin" };
            case "Roderick":
            case "Roderic":
                return new List<string> { "Rick", "Ricky", "Rickie", "Rod", "Roddie", "Roddy" };
            case "Roger":
                return new List<string> { "Rodge", "Hodge", "Hodgekin" };
            case "Rosa":
            case "Rosabella":
            case "Rosalia":
            case "Rosalie":
            case "Rosalind":
                return new List<string> { "Rosie" };
            case "Samuel":
                return new List<string> { "Sam", "Sammy" };
            case "Sarah, Sara":
                return new List<string> { "Sal", "Sally" };
            case "Sebastian":
                return new List<string> { "Seb" };
            case "Silvester":
            case "Sylvester":
                return new List<string> { "Vester", "Vest", "Sil", "Syl" };
            case "Sophia":
                return new List<string> { "Sophie", "Sophy" };
            case "Stephen":
                return new List<string> { "Steve", "Stevie", "Steenie" };
            case "Susan":
            case "Susanna":
            case "Susannah":
                return new List<string> { "Sue", "Suke", "Suky", "Susie", "Susy" };
            case "Theodora":
                return new List<string> { "Dora" };
            case "Theresa":
                return new List<string> { "Terry", "Tracie", "Tracy" };
            case "Thomas":
                return new List<string> { "Tom", "Tommy", "Tam", "Tammie" };
            case "Timothy":
                return new List<string> { "Tim" };
            case "Tobias":
                return new List<string> { "Toby" };
            case "Victor":
                return new List<string> { "Vic" };
            case "Vincent":
                return new List<string> { "Vince", "Vin", "Vinty" };
            case "Walter":
                return new List<string> { "Wat", "Watty" };
            case "Willem":
                return new List<string> { "Wim", "Willie" };
            case "William":
                return new List<string> { "Will", "Willie", "Willy", "Bill", "Billie", "Billy" };
            case "Winifred":
            case "Winfred":
                return new List<string> { "Winnie", "Winny" };
            case "Zachariah":
            case "Zechariah":
                return new List<string> { "Zach", "Zacky", "Zackie", "Zak" };
            default:
                return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```