# Dictionary for listing short names of common names?

Tags: php, dictionary

Can anyone suggest me if there is any dictionary available that will list the set of short names of common names which I need to use in my PHP code.

For ex.

```
Bill = William
Dick = Ricard
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381522/

Answer (score -1):

You can define the names like this.

```
define ("Bill", "William");
```

and you can use these name like this.

```
echo Bill;
```

Comment: Think you didn't get my question and I know how to use these. I am just looking for the Dictionary which lists the set of common names and their corresponding short names.