# create fuzzy logic for name search sql

Tags: sql, fuzzy-logic, soundex

I'm trying to create a fuzzy logic to match similar names like rob and robert. 
The SQL Soundex function for these 2 words is providing a larger difference, which is not useful. Is there another way to find name matches.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple way would be to use the search string "rob*" instead of "rob" or "robert".  This is a crude and simple way and would not work with nicknames that spelled differently than the begining of the fullname. For example, "Bob" wouldn't be caught.

To cover all these nickname and similar names, See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381522/database-of-common-name-aliases-nicknames-of-people)